# About GlassFish Running

Tags: ejb, glassfish-3

I try to run an EJB example using NetBeans IDE and GlassFish Server v3. When I run my client code(The class that have main method), I faced this Error:

Starting GlassFish Server 3.1.2
 GlassFish Server 3.1.2 Server cannot start. Port is occupied.
C:\Users\7\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MDbexample\nbproject\build-impl.xml:907: Deployment error: GlassFish Server 3.1.2 Server cannot start. Port is occupied.

So I decided to run GlassFish by using command line:

c:\glassfish3\bin>asadmin start-domain

Now I faced this massage on cmd environment:

There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.
Command start-domain failed.

Is there anybody that know How I can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

insert line into /etc/hosts  say;

```
<HOSTNAME> <REALIP>
myMachine  10.102.55.45
```

Comment: editing the hosts file did the trick, but if you want to be more generic, arrange your hostname correctly